# Ansible Tower Inventory Groups from playbook

Tags: ansible-inventory, ansible-tower

How can I reference a tower inventory group from the playbook? My playbook is calling specific roles, each role will call on a different inventory group from tower.

So far what I have tried is:

```
host: "{{ inventory_hostname in groups['ios'] }}"
```

or

```
host: "ios"
```

or

```
host: ios
```

Is it just my syntax there on the templating?
I can't find any reference to this when using a tower inventory group.

I get some type of error stating could not be found, or attempting to acctually connect to "ios"

```
"failed to connect to ios:22"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hosts:` instead of `host:` if you want to reference a group.

Comment: I split out my playbook to separate the groups, so I'll put it back to original and try this. Is there documentation for the hosts vs host?

Comment: I would recommend reading this: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#hosts-and-users

Answer (score 0):

From Ansible Tower support:

> Each job template can see only one top-level inventory.  It is possible, though, to create potentially overlapping groups and sub-groups within a single inventory.  For most applications, the single inventory can be organized to provide necessary specificity.  In cases where an particular inventory grouping must be referenced in multiple job templates, it is necessary to either use the same top-level inventory in both cases, or to duplicate the inventory group to both inventories.

So you can't reference other groups in `hosts`, each job template only sees the inventory it was provided but you can either use Workflow to change inventories or create overlapping groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with:
    `hosts: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"`

This "magic variable" gives you the *list* of [active, reachable] Hosts that were passed in from Tower.

I came to this because `hosts:` is a required field in the playbook, and I didn't want to hard-code over the top of the Tower Inventory selection.